# spring-boot-jersey with JAX-RS API 2.1 (SSE)

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, server-sent-events, spring-jersey

What is the timeline for supporting Spring Boot with JAX-RS 2.1 (using Jersey)?

Jersey added support for JAX-RS 2.1 (JAX-RS API) in [Jersey 2.26](https://jersey.github.io/download.html) (released 2017/09/06). This changed the Jersey support for HTTP Server-Sent Events (SSE) from a Jersey specific implementation to an implementation based on the [JAX-RS API](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/index.html?javax/ws/rs/sse/package-summary.html).

The Spring Boot Jersey integration (spring-boot-starter-jersey), release 1.5.8, uses Jersey 2.25.1.

Using spring boot 1.5.8 and overriding the jersey versions from spring-boot-starter-jersey to use 2.26 does not seem to work. The `Sse` and `SseEventSink` objects do not get injected into the request handlers (when using `@Context`).

I am not entirely sure if this is an issue with Spring Boot or Jersey. Hence the more general question, when Spring Boot with JAX-RS 2.1 will be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX-RS 2.1 will be supported via Jersey 2.26 in Spring Boot 2. It has already been [merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10217).